# Alignment of paragraphs within a table

Tags: css

I have a fiddle **[here...](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/j9Vmd/9/)**

Basically, I have a table with multiple columns. There is a column with a paragraph title, and the column next to it with the actual paragraph.

I'm trying to get the paragraph title to align with the top line of the paragraph.

Here's what I've got so far... (tks [**@ExtPro**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404335/extpro))

```
.table-wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.table-col1, .table-col2 { float: left; width: auto;  padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px; }
```

Comment: `vertical-align:top;` CSS property  on `td` tag will probably help you :-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JoshC - No sir. If you look at the text in the fiddle, you'll see the title **Paragraph 1** that needs to line up with the paragraph that starts with **Paragraph 1**, and then the title **Paragraph 2** that should line up with the paragraph that starts with **Paragraph 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are **missing** a ending **tbody** and **table** tag in your **HTML**

also use **vertical-align:top;** to align vertically your table-cell tags. Possible values are: top, middle, bottom

```
Formal syntax: baseline | sub | super | text-top | text-bottom | middle | top | bottom | <percentage> | <length>
```

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align**

**UPDATE:**

what about adding this, set the vertical-align on the tbody > td

```
tbody td {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

if you just did it with **nested tables** it would be like this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/j9Vmd/31/**

Comment: See my comment below. I did as you suggested, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: if your going to use tables, why not just make your table-cells (td) match the same amount of columns and rows instead of floating div's inside the table-cells' ??

Comment: I'm sure I had tried that and it didn't work. I'll take another stab at it. I think the issue I didn't want to run into was that each of the paragraphs I have to line up are different sizes. I didn't want to have to run inline CSS through the entire document. Was trying to solve that with classes.

Comment: added another css to target - **tbody td { vertical-align: top; }**

Comment: Just tried that with the fiddle. It didn't help. Then it brings everything to the top, and I need to line up the title, **Paragraph 1** with the paragraph that starts with **Paragraph 1**, and the same with **Paragraph 2**. Here's an updated fiddle with your fix [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/j9Vmd/23/)

Comment: @webfrogs this is what it would look like if it was a nested table to have it line up without having divs in the TD's. - **http://jsfiddle.net/j9Vmd/31/** - of course there are other ways to do it without tables and only div's

Comment: What you just did will go a long way. Keep coding my friend!

Answer (score 1):

use the property `vertical-align: top;` on your table-col1

Comment: I did as you suggested and it hasn't changed anything. I also added closing `</tbody>` and `</table>` tags. Here's an updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/j9Vmd/13/)

Comment: You've got the entire body of your table in just one row.  You need to separate each paragraph into it's own row with it's respective fields.

Comment: If I do that, it will hurt the table.